# each() + ready() = false?

Tags: html, jquery

Имеется документ в котором есть таблица:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>county</th>
        <th>city</th>
        <td><div class="rem">delete</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>russia</td>
        <td>moscow</td>
        <td><div class="rem">delete</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>usa</td>
        <td>washington</td>
        <td><div class="rem">delete</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>australia</td>
        <td>sidney</td>
        <td><div class="rem">delete</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

есть код, который при помещении в консоль работает, но при добавлении в .html или подгружаемый .js работать отказывается, jQuery подключен, все остальное работает, а этот кусок нет, хотя через консоль проверял логику. все работает нормально, вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $('.rem').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            alert($(this).parents('td').siblings('td:first').text());
        });
    });

});
```

**alert должен выводить название страны..**
Помогите разобраться, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Надо писать так:

```
$(function(){
    $('table').on('click', '.rem', function(){
        alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>county</th>
        <th>city</th>
        <th class="rem">action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>russia</td>
        <td>moscow</td>
        <td class="rem">delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>usa</td>
        <td>washington</td>
        <td class="rem">delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>australia</td>
        <td>sidney</td>
        <td class="rem">delete</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $('.rem').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            alert($(this).siblings('td:first').text());
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: не работает тоже

Comment: @pirogi Добавил полный текст скрипта. У меня всё работает. Если у вас нет, то проблема в чем-то другом.

Comment: поправил html там в последнем td лежит div он с классом rem,но мой код не работает все равно

Comment: @pirogi Если элемент в ячейке всего один, можно ей задать класс и использовать мою функцию для клика по ней. В ином же случае до утра помочь не смогу. Уже не за компьютером.

Comment: элемента 2, не стал тут второй писать, но вы поймите, я открываю свою страничцу он не работает, открываю консоль, пишу его туда и он сразу начинает работать...мне это непонятно

Comment: @pirogi примечателен тот факт, что ваш код на моей пустой странице работает отлично. Чуть выше norbornen предложил свой вариант. Он тоже работает. Попробуйте его. Если не получится, публикуйте весь код страницы, будем смотреть.